# FMDB: is It good remaininig open database during the whole life cycle of ios app?

Tags: ios, fmdb

I am confused about database open and close operation for FMDB wrapper class.

Is it creating issue if i open database in 
applicationDidFinishLoading method of AppDelegate class
and do not close until application will terminate ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Official FMDB documentation:

**Opening**

Before you can interact with the database, it must be opened. Opening fails if there are insufficient resources or permissions to open and/or create the database.

```
if (![db open]) {
[db release];
return;
}
```

**Closing**

When you have finished executing queries and updates on the database, ***you should close the FMDatabase connection so that SQLite will relinquish any resources it has acquired during the course of its operation.***

```
[db close];
```

So, every time your query the Database, you should have a pair of `open` and `close` calls on your database.

In short, open a DB connection when you require things from database and close it when you are done using the database.

Link to documentation : https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

Comment: so what are the drawbacks if i am not closing database with in whole life cycle of iOS application?

Comment: `SQLite will relinquish any resources it has acquired during the course of its operation.`, from the documentation, if you don't close the connection the resources acquired by SQLite will not be freed and your application will have memory issues.

Comment: If you are doing lots of queries however, you're better off keeping the database open.  There's a hit in performance when you open up a database, and honestly, the resources sqlite takes up isn't very much.  Just keep it open.

Answer (score 7):

There's no reason to close it unless you change the schema.  So keep it open.

Comment: Its good if when app is in foreground more that time db open and when app goes in background mode db.close ?

Comment: And if db open and it will not use long time than it will close automatically ?